# Find constants so that the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z) = axy^2+byz+cx^3z^2$ has maximum value $32$ in point $P$ given the direction

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am asked to find $a$, $b$ and $c$ so that the directional derivative of $$f(x,y,z) = axy^2+byz+cx^3z^2$$ has maximum value of $32$ in the point $P(1,2,-1)$ and in the direction $\overrightarrow{u} = (0,0,1)$.

What I have so far is

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = ay^2 + 3cx^2z^2\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2axy+bz\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = by+2cx^3z\\
\nabla f(1,2,-1) = (4a+3c,4a-b,2b-2c)$$

$$
D_{u} f(1,2,-1) = (4a+3c, 4a-b, 2b-2c) \cdot (0,0,1) = 32 \therefore b-c = 16
$$

and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer: 
$$a = 3\\
b = 12\\
c = -4$$

Comment: Try using systems of equations

Comment: @Red I have one equation. What would be the other two? Thank you.

Comment: The max the of directional derivative occurs when the gradient and $u$ have the same direction.

Comment: The requirement that grad$f$ have the same direction as $u$ gives some equations.

Comment: @spinoza thank you for the input. But that would just say that $4a+3c=0$ and $4a-c=0$. Am I making a mistake here? I'll make a small edit on the post in one minute.

Comment: @spinoza ahh I got it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

5. Find values of the constants $a, b, c$ such that the directional derivative of $$f(x, y, z) = axy^2 +
   byz +cz^2x^3$$ at the point $(1, 2, −1)$ has a maximum value of $32$ in the direction parallel to the $z$-axis.
   First compute the gradient:
   $$\nabla f = (ay^2 + 3cz^2x^2)i + (2axy + bz)j + (by + 2czx^3)k$$
   and
   $$\nabla f(1, 2, −1) = (4a + 3c)i + (4a − b)j + (2b − 2c)k$$
   We know that the gradient vector points in the direction of the greatest rate of change. So, if $f$
   attains a maximum value in a direction parallel to the $z$-axis, this means that $\nabla f(1, 2, −1)$ points
   in a direction parallel to the $z$-axis (but we don’t know if it points up or down). This gives the
   equations
   $$4a + 3c = 0, \quad 
    4a − b = 0, \quad
    2b − 2c = 32$$
   where the final equation follows from the fact that we know that the maximum value attained by $f$
   is $64$, and the fact that the maximum value of the gradient vector equals the length of the gradient
   vector. Solving this, we get
   $$(a, b, c) = (3, 12, −4) \text{ or } (a, b, c) = (−3,12,-4)$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).