# Find constants of $f(x,y,z) = axy^2+byz+cx^3z^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I have little problem regarding the [Find constants so that the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z) = axy^2+byz+cx^3z^2$ has maximum value $32$ in point $P$ given the direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1729767/805838) .

In this problem there is no accept answer that is why I am asking
As I think since maximum value is $32$  $|\nabla f(1,2,-1)|=\sqrt(2b-2c)^2=\pm (2b-2c)=32$

So we can get two answer

Is it correct?

Comment: it says maximum value in $(0, 0, 1)$ direction so there will be only one solution $a = 3, b = 12, c = -4$

Comment: @MathLover Thank you very much